# How to extract article content from a website/blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I'm trying to write a generic function for extracting article text from blog posts and websites.

A few simplified examples I'd like to be able to process:

Random website:

```
...
<div class="readAreaBox" id="readAreaBox">
  <h1 itemprop="headline">title</h1>
  <div class="chapter_update_time">time</div>
  <div class="p" id="chapterContent">article text</div>
</div>
...
```

Wordpress:

```
<div id="main" class="site-main">
  <div id="primary" class="site-content" role="main">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
      <article id="post-1234" class="post-1234 post type-post">
        <div class="entry-meta clear">..</div>
        <h1 class="entry-title">title</h1>
        <div class="entry-content clear">
          article content
          <div id="jp-post-flair" class="sharedaddy">sharing links</div>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Blogspot:

```
<div id="content">
  ...
  <div class="main" id="main">
    <div class="post hentry">
      <h3 class="post-title">title</h3>
      <div class="post-header">...</div>
      <div class="post-body">article content</div>
      <div class="post-footer">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I came up with (doc is a `Nokogiri::HTML::Document`):

```
def fetch_content
  html = ''
  ['#content', '#main', 'article', '.post-body', '.entry-content', '#chapterContent'].each do |css|
    candidate = doc.css(css).to_html
    html = [html, candidate].select(&:present?).sort_by(&:length).first
  end
  self.content = html
end
```

It works relatively well for the examples I tested with but it still leaves some sharing and navigation links plus it won't work if a page uses more cryptic class names.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: It's not really about code review, more about web scraping techniques and/or libraries people who don't do this professionally might not be aware of. As it's a bit of an open question and it doesn't look like there is a definite answer, I'll accept one of the answers I received.

Comment: That would be off-topic because tool and library recommendations are.

Comment: It isn't possible to write generic code to handle all sites out there, because sites vary too much. You can *sometimes* write generic code to handle a particular site's pages if they generate their pages using templates, but even then advertising and DHTML can mess you up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a gem called [pismo](https://github.com/peterc/pismo) that implements a couple of algorithms that attempts to extract article content.

There is a java library [boilerpipe](https://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/) which you can interface from JRuby which extract textual content of a webpage.

Comment: `pismo` is really good at extracting titles but the content extraction works for me only for 'standard' blogs and is very aggressive at removing formatting. I'll read its code though maybe it will give me some ideas. 
Boilerpipe looks good too, even if troublesome to use with ruby, I'll take a look at it, thanks.

Comment: Pismo has 3 extraction algo's. `tree.rb`, `base.rb` and `cluster.rb`. I think `tree.rb` gave me the best general performance. If you want better performance than `pismo` or `boilerpipe` you would need to write your own machine learning algorithm. I have used Random Forests in the past to extract useful links from webpages. Machine learning algos will handle edge cases better than heuristic based approaches and will scale better as the model becomes more clever by adding more training data, as apposed to crafting better heuristics.

Answer (score 1):

Use [rapar](https://github.com/jiren/raspar) this gives the facility to write domain specific parser like wordpress.com, blogspot.com etc

Comment: Looks better for detailed parsing of a specific website than for generic parsing of many sites and doesn't look to be very actively developed but I'll take a look at it, thanks.

Comment: I use it, its well maintained

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a free article extraction API, for example:

[diffbot.com](https://www.diffbot.com)
[embed.ly](http://embed.ly/extract)
[textracto.com](http://textracto.com)

Some of them work quite good, and as I know there are all easy to integrate with Ruby.